# Trying to push back in gitlab pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-push

I am new to ci processes. But I ran into the following: when I create a new version of the package, during the execution of the pipeline, it updates the record in the file. I need to do a git push, but I ran into different problems and got confused about which tokens to use. We have our own server with gitlab, which runs pipelines.

```
function try_push_back() {
  git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
  cd "$CI_PROJECT_NAME"

  git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
  git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"

  echo "$CI_JOB_ID" > output.txt
  git add output.txt
  git commit -m "[skip ci] Updating output.txt with latest CI_JOB_ID." >&2

  git push "http://${PERSONAL_USERNAME}:${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git" HEAD:"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" >&2
}
```

With following code i have the next result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8x3d.png)

Comment: Maybe there are some templates? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it myself. Following code is work for me.

```
  echo "committing version number to sfdx-project.json" >&2
  git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:$PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git"
  git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
  git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
  echo "$CI_JOB_ID" > output.txt
  git add output.txt
  git commit -m "[skip ci] Updating output.txt with latest CI_JOB_ID." >&2
  git status
  git push origin HEAD:"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" >&2
```